# How to benchmark maxCache 3.0 with SSDs?

Tags: database, cache, ssd, io, adaptec

We're a software development company and previously outsourced the HW side of business but now we're looking into building our own private cloud. We recently purchased a few servers, one of which is supposed to act as a central storage. The specs are as follows:

- Chassis: CSE-826BE16-R920LPB Motherboard: Supermicro X10SLL-F CPU
- E3-1200v3,Intel C222, 2GbE, Up to 32GB DDR3 ECC,2xSATA3,4xSATA2, 4xDDR3 IPMI
- 1x CPU Intel Xeon E3-1220v3 - 3.1GHz, 8MB cache, 4core, HT, LGA1150, 80W
- 1x heatsink SNK-0046A4 Activ 2U
- 4x 8GB Samsung M391B1G73QH0-CK0 1600MHz DDR3 ECC Unbuffered 2R×8
- 2x SSD 80GB Intel DC S3500 Series 2,5" SATA3, read 340 MB/s, write 100 MB/s
- 10x HDD 2TB Seagate Constellation ES.3 ST2000NM0023 3,5" SAS2, 7200rpm, 128MB

The Seagate drives are set up as RAID 6 array. The SSDs are in RAID 1 and act as maxCache container which we turn on and off using maxView Storage Manager.

**My first question** - does this configuration make sense for a central storage of a private cloud where we plan to have other 3 compute nodes with two CPUs and lots of RAM on them?

**My second question** - would a similar configuration with less HDDs make sense for a MySQL database server for a reporting system with many concurrent requests? Or would it make more sense to use the SSDs for MySQL's temp space where it creates temporary tables.

And now for the **main question**... I tried to measure performance of this server with and without SSD cache (maxCache). The best tool I came across was iozone (iozone -a -g 8G) which produced these charts: http://www.bugweis.com/storage/comparison.zip. I am totally puzzled as it looks like the performance with maxCache is in most cases lower than without it.

I was wondering if iozone is a good way to test for real-life scenarios or if I'm doing this all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> does this configuration make sense for a central storage of a private
>   cloud where we plan to have other 3 compute nodes with two CPUs and
>   lots of RAM on them?

I'd be worried that you have a single-point-of-failure here as it will only act as a single-controller storage box, you've also not really got a lot of memory (get more, it's cheap) and it looks like your only networking is 2 x 1Gbps NICs - they'll be a massive choke-point in this setup. So no I wouldn't recommend this - what price have you been given for this?

> would a similar configuration with less HDDs make sense for a MySQL
>   database server for a reporting system with many concurrent requests?
>   Or would it make more sense to use the SSDs for MySQL's temp space
>   where it creates temporary tables.

I'd be tempted to go for a two socket system for a DB box, even if you don't use the second socket right away - database engines tend to scale well with more cores. Again you'd want a lot more memory. As for what disks to use - well it would be foolish to make any suggestions here as DB IO requirements vary more than just about any part of an infrastructure based on the read/write balance and a lot of other factors such as the table sizes etc.

Comment: Yeah the single point of failure is definitely a concern but at this point we cannot afford to build a highly available infrastructure. You said 32G is not a lot of RAM - well how much would you suggest for a server that only works as a data storage? We paid about 3800 EUR for this server.

Comment: The network cards both have two physical ports so it's actually 4 x 1Gbps. Still a potential bottleneck I presume?

Comment: Sorry, just realized the description is missing the number of RAM units.

Comment: I'd still rather use a dual-controller system such as a HP P2000 G3 array

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE - this is what Adaptec support said:

> The benefit of Maxcache writes and reads occurs only when the system
>   has run for a long enough period to populate the "Hot Data" on the ssd
>   drives. This would take some time depending on the data written and
>   the requests made to the system, so a short benchmarking test may not
>   show any improvement, as it may not allow enough time for the "Hot
>   data" to populate the drives.Please also make sure that the
>   outstanding I/O values are set 32 or 64, as some benchmarking software
>   packages set the deafult value to 1, whcih would affect performance
>   values obtained and would not be correct.

So I guess iozone is not the best way to test maxCache performance.